# How to do offline installer for windows .net framework?

Tags: .net, docker

I'm new to docker,
How to do .net framework offline installer for windows using powershell ?

Here im trying create a new docker file .net framework offline installer

I'm unable to create there is no proper way.

Comment: Which version of .NET Framework?

Comment: Have you looked at the official .NET Framework Docker images at https://hub.docker.com/_/microsoft-dotnet-framework? These already have .NET Framework pre-installed.  Are these not sufficient for your needs?